# Firebase Cloud Function not executing

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions

I'm working on the group functionality of my app where members of the group can add task to a group that they are currently working on. So, when a task is added I want to notify all members using FCM that a task had been added to the group.

**EDIT:**

The code to add the task to a group is run on the client and works successfully. The purpose of the cloud function is just to send cloud messages to all the members of the group that a task has been added by a particular member.

This is my logic for the cloud function :
1st. As a task can be added to multiple groups at a time I'm using a `forEach()`.
2nd. I'm fetching the uids of the Members in the groups and pushing them into an array(`uids`) so that later I can retrieve their fcmTokens.
3rd. Running a `forEach` on the `uids` to retrieve the fcmTokens.
4th.Sending Cloud message to devices.

But the cloud function doesn't execute as expected.

This my cloud function:

```js
exports.newTaskAdded = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
  const groups = data.groups; //Can be multiple groups hence an array.
  const uid = data.uid;
  const author = data.author;
  const taskId = data.taskId;
  const taskTitle = data.taskTitle;
try {
    groups.forEach(async group => {
      const groupName = group.groupName;
      console.log('groupName: ', groupName);
      const groupId = groups.groupId;

      const membersPromises = [];
      membersPromises.push(
        admin
          .firestore()
          .collection('Groups')
          .doc(`${groupId}`)
          .collection('Members') //Members collection has document for each user with their uid as the document name.
          .get(),
      );

      console.log('memberPromises: ', membersPromises);//Function stops after this.

      const membersSnapshot = await Promise.all(membersPromises); 
      console.log('membersSnapshots', membersSnapshot);
      const uids = [];
      membersSnapshot.forEach(doc => {
        doc.forEach(snap => {
          console.log(snap.id);
          uids.push(snap.id);
        });
      });
      console.log(uids);

      const uidPromises = [];
      uids.forEach(uid => {
        uidPromises.push(
          admin
            .firestore()
            .collection('Users')
            .doc(`${uid}`)
            .get(),
        );
      });

      console.log('uidPromises: ', uidPromises);
      const tokensSnapshots = await Promise.all(uidPromises);

      const notifPromises = [];
      tokensSnapshots.forEach(snap => {
        console.log(snap.data());
        const token = Object.keys(snap.data().fcmTokens);
        const payload = {
          notification: {
            title: `${author} has added a new task to ${groupName}`,
            body: `Task Added: ${taskTitle}`,
            sound: 'default',
          },
        };

        notifPromises.push(admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token, payload));
      });

      await Promise.all(notifPromises);
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }

  return {result: 'OK'};
});
```

This is my log: 
[image]

As you can see there is no error shown.

Help would be very much appreciated. Thank you

Comment: See https://codeburst.io/javascript-async-await-with-foreach-b6ba62bbf404

Comment: Okay, I’ll take a look thanks

Comment: What are you expecting this function to do?  What is the code that invokes it from the client?  Please edit the question to make it clear what should be happening.

Comment: @DougStevenson I have edited the question

Comment: I think you have not deployed your function properly.

Comment: @AmitTiwary I have, otherwise it would show warnings or errors while deploying

Comment: you have only hosted your cloud function?

Comment: @AmitTiwary Yes

Comment: it happens with me once. You need to deploy and also host cloud function.